# Triggering "change" event on jQuery datepicker filled with jQuery val() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, datepicker

i'm trying to trigger 'change' event on jQuery datepicker input after populating it with jQuery val() method (i'm not 'selecting' value but injecting it with jquery val()). Problem is that it's not working - input field is not saving inserted value and form doesn't see it (and prevents submit). My code is:

```js
var date1 = 27/02/2018;
var newdate = date1.split("/").reverse().join("-"); 
var selection = $('#date_field').val(newdate);
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("change", true, true);
selection.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

I was trying also 'input' event but it's not working either.

Please, if you know how can i trigger change event on datepicker input give me some advice.

Cheers,
Paul

Comment: `selection` is a jQuery object, so just `selection.change()` will raise the event. If this doesn't have the effect you are looking for then its likely that the event handler you're trying to trigger is not bound to that element

Comment: Ok, i understand now. I checked fields Event Handlers and there is no 'change' event there. But there is: 'blur', 'click, 'copy', 'cut', 'error', 'focus', 'focusin', 'focusout', 'keydown', 'keypress', 'keyup', 'load', 'message', 'mousedown', 'mouseup', 'paste', 'textinput'. I tried 'keyup' and 'blur' events, because i thought that change is triggered on blur probably but it just clears inserted value.... How can i save inserted value in that field? Maybe there is some other posibility to achieve 'change' on this type of field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jquery you can trigger a event with trigger() function:

```
$('#date_field').trigger("change");
```

Then if there is some action associated with change event that will be triggered.

Comment: Unfortunately - it's not working. There is no 'change' event bounded to this field as i said in my answer to Rory McCrossan post. There are other events though but i don' know how to use them in this case.

Comment: This is an example to change event to data_field:  $('#data_field').change(function (e) {
   $(this).val(); // get the value of the input
   //can put here other code that you want
});

Answer (score 0):

1. Create 2 hidden fields (name & id): startDate and endDate
2. Then adjust the js code inside the daterangepicker initialization related to start/end function to add the values to hidden fields and make use of them further in your desired action:

```
function(start, end)
{
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    $('#startDate').val(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    $('#endDate').val(end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    // some other action you want
}
```